# ASP.net Dynamic GridViews with Hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, matrix, dynamic-data

I have a database with students, and a weekly figure based upon them. I would like to create a gridview, with a dynamically expanding set of columns and rows, whereby Rows are weeks 1,2,...,n and columns represent each student, or vice versa.

```
Reviews data table looks like this:
======================================
| Stu#  | Week# | Score    | Review# |
--------------------------------------
| 123   | 1     | A+       | 832     |
| 123   | 2     | C-       | 352     |
.       .       .          .         .
.       .       .          .         . 
.       .       .          .         .
| 321   | 12    | B        | 992     |
| 321   | 13    | A-       | 935     |
======================================
```

So basically, I would like to pull out a review for

In each of these cells I would like to have a weekly figure based on a review submitted on them, and a link to this review. Much like:

```
 _____________________________
| Week | StudentA  | StudentB |
| No.  |   (123)   |  (321)   |
-------------------------------
|   1  |    A+     |   B-     |
|   2  |    ...    |   ...    |
.      .           .          . 
.      .           .          . 
.      .           .          . 
|  13  |     A+    |   B-     |
-------------------------------
```

I have looked at a few (hundred) similar, yet not identical problems in an attempt to stich something together, but so far have been dumfounded.
It's almost like it would represent an excel spreadsheet with links to specific data entries.

I had a go at creating a List, within a list whereby but that became too muddled.
Then I tried doing it with a DataTable, whereby the columns and rows were created at the start, but didnt know how to DataBind() the table inclusive of hyperlinks (in the form of URLParameters to an aspx page of course).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've gone ahead and generated a DataTable dynamically and bound it to my GridView, which workd perfectly fine for plaintext results, but I would like to create hyperlinks for each element (ie, the A+) so a particular mark can be read, with comments etc.

I tried adding an  tag, but thanks to ASP.net's code-injection protection, it didnt quite work. so basically I had:

```
 HyperLink thisScore = new HyperLink();
            thisScore.NavigateUrl=string.Format("<a href='studentMarks.aspx?groupID={0}&week={1}&studentID={2}'>{3}</a>", groupID, week, reader["student_ID"], reader[studentScoreLocation]);
            newRow[studentName] = thisScore;
```

Followed by an attempt to use a HyperLink objet (to no avail)

```
        HyperLink thisScore = new HyperLink();
        thisScore.NavigateUrl=string.Format("studentMarks.aspx?groupID={0}&week={1}&studentID={2}", groupID, week, reader["student_ID"]);
        thisScore.Text = reader[studentScoreLocation].ToString();
        newRow[studentName] = thisScore;
```

What would be the best way to get around this?